# Given a shape file for a US state, find the shape file for a single county

Tags: r, shapefile

I have a shape file in R of the entire state of Kentucky.

[image]

I can successfully plot the tracts using `spplot(s1, z="TRACT")` However I need only COUNTY 111. I tried `s1[s1&"COUNTY"=="111"]` but I don't think I'm allowed to compare strings that way. I tried `subset(s1, "COUNTY" == "111")` but this gave me a data frame with no shape data, it was empty.

Answer (score 0):

`s1[s1&"COUNTY"=="111"]` fails because you've used `&`. You use `$` to extract columns. Also you've put quote marks round the column name.

`onecounty = s1[s1$COUNTY == "035",]` should work - note there are *no* quotes round the column name. I've used `035` because I can see from the summary that there is an 035 - I can't see if there's a 111.

`subset(s1, COUNTY == "035")` should also work, you quoted `"COUNTY"` so it was comparing the string `"COUNTY"` with the string `"111"` which meant they were never equal so an empty set was returned.